# background-image logo hovered by other divs

Tags: html, css

So i have an id of logo, and there is a logo image puted as background-image. I am making mobile webpage,so other divs are ignoring it and are in front of it.

html

```
<header id="header" class="calign group">
    <a id="logo" class="png ru" href="http://www.web.ru/">Webname</a>
    <!--other divs-->
</header>
```

css

```
#logo.ru {
background: url("images/logo.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
```

Comment: where is the class `.ru` ?

Comment: <a id="logo" class="ru" href="http://www.web.ru/">Webname</a>

Comment: could you make a fiddle and your code is not clear enough

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: In your case, you need to use sprite images and then refer the small one for mobile devices using media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest jquery, CSS sibling selectors are limited. It would be to easy for it to break because additional content was added to the page.

```
<header id="header" class="calign group">
    <!--other divs-->
    <a id="logo" class="png ru" href="http://www.web.ru/">Webname</a>
</header>

#header div:hover~a {
/* these rules apply on hover to the a element. 
An a element that comes after this one, but not necessarily 
immediately after. In other word #logo.ru */ 
}
```

And #logo would need to be positioned with CSS back to where you wanted it.